# How can I prevent the first element of a side-nav from hiding under the top nav under certain conditions?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

How can I prevent the side-nav from hiding the top element in the vanilla bootstrap 4 example below?

## (Fixed - see below)

It's happening on my web site, as well as the Bootstrap Official (url given below): 
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/dashboard/

### My environment

- Windows 10
- Works as fine in Edge
- Works as displayed below in Chrome Version 79.0.3945.117 (Official Build) (64-bit)

### Visual Example

- When page is first loaded: [image]
- When page is "a) shift-refreshed or (b) scroll to bottom of the page and shift-refresh" [image]

.sidebar {
    top: 48px; <------- change from 0 to 48px
    ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see, this is happening when you are setting the .sidebar class. You are setting the top to 0 which is sending it behind the top nav-bar. I think that the reason why it is happening on the refresh is because that nav-bar is sticky and they are then overlapping at the same top position. When I go into the Chrome Dev-Tools and unmark that setting then it shows the top option.